# Checking image with Google Vision using CloudFunctions in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-vision

I was trying to follow up on a Tutorial. To examine an Image on a Document Creation, here is the Firestore information:

[image: User Table inside Firestore]

The image is stored as a link inside this document on the field image_url.

I have created a Cloud Function using the Dependency (Node Module):

***"@google-cloud/vision": "^2.4.0",***

My index File looks like this:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';
import vision from '@google-cloud/vision';

const env = functions.config();

//Function to check Images on User Create.

exports.checkUserAvatarImage = functions.firestore.document('users/{uid}').onCreate(async (userSnap, context) => {
    const content = userSnap.data();

    if(content.startsWith("http")){
        return (async () => {
            const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

            const [result] = await client.safeSearchDetection(content);
            var detections = result.safeSearchAnnotation;
            
            if(detections?.adult == 'LIKELY' || detections?.adult == 'VERY_LIKELY' || detections?.adult == 'POSSIBLE'){
                return userSnap.ref.update({
                    'image_url': 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/realstatestb-ad581.appspot.com/o/user_images%2FCasaVerde.png?alt=media&token=ae018b20-858c-4ead-a64a-1871b4e22652'
                });
            }
            return;
        })()
        .then(() => {
            return;
        }).catch(err => console.log("An error has ocurred " + err));
    }
    return;
});
```

The problem is that when I upload an Adult Content image doesn't change it for the one shown in the code, however when I check the logs on Functions always says it starts and ends with "Ok".

[image: Logs]

Any ideas?

Thank you for any guidence.

Comment: Hi @Rene, Can you please give us the output of 'detections.adult' if you put in console.log(). Thank you.

Comment: hey I got an error today: 

checkUserAvatarImage
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Guys after the valuable input of Marc, I understood the problem the issue wasn't here but the way I sent the data to the Firestore, as when user gets created the Image isn't uploaded yet.

Here is the code:

```
case "Signup":
          {
            authResult = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: email,
              password: password,
            );

            final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
                .ref()
                .child('user_images')
                .child(authResult.user.uid + '.jpg');

            await ref.putFile(image);

            final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();

            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('users')
                .doc(authResult.user.uid)
                .set({
              'username': username,
              'email': email,
              'image_url': url,
              'name': fullname,
              'phone': 0,
            }).then((_) => {
                      // Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).getUserInfo(
                      //   url, fullname, email, username, authResult.user.uid);

                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(ExploreSellScreen
                          .routeName) //NewMainScreen.routeName) //ListingOverviewScreen.routeName)
                    });
          }
          break;
```

So I think now I have to find a way to upload this on Create and not as an Update. Thank you for those who read this question, and sorry for this detail.

Also if you have any suggestions please let me know.